# TYPO3 Fluid uri action ignoring parameters?

Tags: ajax, typo3, fluid

I have this inline fluid call:

```
{f:uri.action(pageUid: 102, action: 'getFile', noCacheHash: true, additionalParams: {id: 102})}
```

However, it seems like the parameters "pageUid", "noCacheHash" and "additionalParams" are ignored, since the resulting url looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/excontroller/?no_cache=1&tx_excontroller_bmbf%5Baction%5D=getFile&tx_excontroller_bmbf%5Bcontroller%5D=excontroller&cHash=cec99a845beead4fe9f3863494abf1c7
```

Since its an ajax call, I would glady disable the cHash. Or at least pass the pageUid so I don't get the "cHash calculation"-Error.

So, am I missing something? Why are the parameters not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the `noCacheHash: true` I guess that fluid interprets the true as if it were a varibale. Try `noCacheHash: 1` instead.

As for `additionalParams` that are params that are not prefixed. If you want them to be prefixed just like the action, use `arguments`.

*Edit: Removed bad advice from the answer. Thank you, Claus.*

Comment: Excuse me budging in but regarding the recommendation to put single quotes around the array I strongly advise against it. Detailed reasoning can be found in https://vimeo.com/167666466 but long story short: this will begin to become an unsupported use case and is no longer handled in Fluid standalone. The other recommendation to use `1` rather than `true` is absolutely correct and quite mandatory. It gets seen as a variable reference which contains `null` as value and that gives boolean `false` when cast, contrary to intent.

Comment: Thank you Claus for the comment. This means that `{f:uri.action(arguments: {id: 102})}` is correct? Frankly I did not test any of it :)

Comment: `{f:uri.action(arguments: {id: 102})}` is correct syntax but don't forget that this particular ViewHelper has a mandatory `action` argument, so maybe you'd want to add a dummy argument to make it correct syntax and correct usage ;)

Comment: Changing `noCacheHash` to `1` resolved my issue, thanks. No idea why I didnt try that on my own.